# Android ObjectAnimator+ValueAnimator laggy

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I try to make expanding layout animation and `translation` animation of `ImageView`, but I start them together  they look  little laggy. I tested  it on real device Moto X(2013). Not sure about more powerfull devices, because all my emulated phones are laggy by default :).

I also tried to turn on `HardwareType`

`View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);`

but this also didn't give result.

So here's code of translation:

```
 ObjectAnimator translate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 0f, 380.0f);

    translate.setDuration(500);
    translate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    translate.start();
```

And layout expanding:

```
va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(340, 904);
    va.setDuration(500);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            user_container.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
            user_container.requestLayout();
            System.out.println("value = " + value.intValue() );
        }
    });
```

Nothing special. So, can somebody tell me, how to make to animation in time not laggy?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should measure what takes up so much time. Usually it's your draw method if you have a custom view. If not, you are usually doing other things on the main thread that are taking too much time - i.e. having movement or update listeners that are accessing I/O or similar.

Try to kick out the log line for starters. And try not to call `requestLayout()` just to see what happens and if it makes any difference. If your `user_container` is very complex then you will definitely experience lagging.

Btw, don't use emulators if you're testing something that can vary from device to device :)